# Computing a determinantal representation of a bivariate polynomial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, na.numerical-analysis, real-algebraic-geometry

Let $p \in \mathbb R [x,y,z]$ be a homogeneous irreducible polynomial of degree $d$.  From Dickson in 1920 we know that there exists $A$, $B$ and $C$ such that

$$\det (Ax + By + Cz) = c p(x,y,z)$$

where $c$ is some constant.

Vinnikov in 1988 was able to describe all the non-equivalent determinantal representations as points on the Jacobian variety that are not on the exceptional sub variety.  The theoretical work in this paper is relatively constructive, but is still a long way from a numerically stable constructive algorithm for $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Given any polynomial $p(x,y,z)$, can one triple $(A, B,C)$ be constructed in a numerically stable way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is discussed in a recent work of Plaumann, Sturmfels and Vinzant:

http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.6057